# What does a , operator do when used in the right hand side of a conditional?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = 10
b = 20
c = 30
if(a > b,c):
    print('In if')
else:
    print('In else')
```

Someone posted the above piece of code, and asked why the above always results in 'In if', being printed regardless of the values of b and c.

Although this seems like poor programming style, I am curious what the `,` operator is doing.

I have not been able to find an answer in the documentation so far. Can anyone provide an explanation ?

Comment: An equivalent script is simply the single line `print('In if')`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a > b, c` is the tuple `((a > b), c)`.

So if `a=10, b=20, c=30`, then we're asking if the tuple `(False, 30)` is [truish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false). All non-empty tuples are truish, so this would always trigger the same path through the conditional.

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
>>> 5>4,5
(True, 5)
```

It outputs a tuple where the elements are  `the result of 5>4` and `5`

as 5>4 equals `True`

The output will be `(True, 5)`

Answer (score 2):

let me start by explaining the what the tuple is resulting:

in your case , since `a>b` is false, the first part of the tuple is `False` .

so the `(a>b,c)` , would look something like `(False, 30)`.

Now you are asking if a tuple has some content in it. Yes , it is of course having the content and that is `(False, 30)`.

That is why your `if` check is always passing irrespective of values of `a,b,c`.

If an empty tuple is passed in to the `if clause` , then you will see the `if clause` failing, as shown below.

```
>>> if():
    print('In if')
else:
    print('In else')

    
In else
```

Regards